# What can I do with my trading cards?

Tags: snoopys-street-fair

I have a lot of extra trading cards.

Can I do something with them? Is it possible to share them with a friend (if I had one)? Or just get rid of them? Or am I just stuck with them?

Comment: I would like to point out (because I suspect this is why I got downvotes) that I am talking about virtual trading cards in an iOS game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trade them for cards you need with friends. You can request friends and find friends in the Game Center. I am tiffalonis. Be my friend! :)